# how to use or_where and where condition in ajax datables in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, datatables

How to get and condition in OR condition. And condition used after OR is not working.

```
$this->datatables->select('otest_questions.qst_id,otest_sub_category.sub_cat_name,otest_subjects.subject_display_name,otest_questions.qst_question,otest_questions.qst_status');
        $this->datatables->join('otest_subjects',' otest_questions.qst_subject_id=otest_subjects.subject_id');
        $this->datatables->join('otest_main_category','otest_subjects.subject_main_cat_id=otest_main_category.main_cat_id');
        $this->datatables->join('otest_sub_category','otest_main_category.main_cat_id=otest_sub_category.sub_cat_main_cat_id');
        $this->datatables->where(array('otest_questions.qst_added_by'=>$this->session->userdata['inst_in']['inst_id'],'otest_questions.qst_chapter_id'=>$this->input->get('chapter')));
        $this->datatables->or_where(array('otest_questions.access_level'=>1));
        $this->datatables->where(array('otest_questions.qst_chapter_id'=>$this->input->get('chapter')));

        $this->datatables->group_by('otest_questions.qst_id');
        $this->datatables->from('otest_questions');
        }

        echo $this->datatables->generate();
```

The query executed is

SELECT * FROM (`otest_questions`) JOIN `otest_subjects` ON `otest_questions`.`qst_subject_id`=`otest_subjects`.`subject_id` JOIN `otest_main_category` ON `otest_subjects`.`subject_main_cat_id`=`otest_main_category`.`main_cat_id` JOIN `otest_sub_category` ON `otest_main_category`.`main_cat_id`=`otest_sub_category`.`sub_cat_main_cat_id` **WHERE `otest_questions`.`qst_added_by` = '12' AND `otest_questions`.`qst_chapter_id` = '988' AND `otest_questions`.`qst_chapter_id` = '988' OR `otest_questions`.`access_level` = 1** GROUP BY `otest_questions`.`qst_id`.

But the query should be

**WHERE `otest_questions`.`qst_added_by` = '12' AND `otest_questions`.`qst_chapter_id` = '988'  OR `otest_questions`.`access_level` = 1 AND `otest_questions`.`qst_chapter_id` = '988'**

Comment: `group_by` need `order by` clause as well

Comment: or_where should check the same database column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$inst_id = $this->session->userdata['inst_in']['inst_id'];
$chapter = $this->input->get('chapter');

$query = "SELECT * FROM (otest_questions)
JOIN otest_subjects ON otest_questions.qst_subject_id=otest_subjects.subject_id 
JOIN otest_main_category ON otest_subjects.subject_main_cat_id=otest_main_category.main_cat_id 
JOIN otest_sub_category ON otest_main_category.main_cat_id=otest_sub_category.sub_cat_main_cat_id 
WHERE (otest_questions.qst_added_by = '$inst_id' AND otest_questions.qst_chapter_id = '$chapter')
OR (otest_questions.qst_chapter_id = '$chapter' AND otest_questions.access_level = 1)
GROUP BY otest_questions.qst_id";

$this->datatables->query($query);
```

Comment: i wanted to use and condition in or_where.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query = "(SELECT a.qst_id,d.sub_cat_name,b.subject_display_name,a.qst_question,a.qst_status from otest_questions as a JOIN otest_subjects as b ON a.qst_subject_id = b.subject_id JOIN otest_main_category as c ON b.subject_main_cat_id = c.main_cat_id JOIN otest_sub_category as d ON c.main_cat_id = d.sub_cat_main_cat_id WHERE a.qst_added_by =".$this->session->userdata['inst_in']['inst_id'] ." AND a.qst_chapter_id =".$this->input->get('chapter')." OR a.access_level = 1 AND a.qst_chapter_id =".$this->input->get('chapter')." GROUP BY a.qst_id) as F";
    $this->datatables->select('*');
    $this->datatables->from($query);
    echo $this->datatables->generate();
```